# Code throws Invalid cast exception: linq-sql join two tables

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm new to sql-linq and I'm trying to join two tables using their common id which is MOTHERID. But the code below is throwing an "Invalid cast exception" at:

var firstQuery = (from s in _maternalvisitvaluedb.Value select s).ToList();

and the whole code looks like:

```
var firstQuery = (from s in _maternalvisitvaluedb.Value select s).ToList();
var secondQuery = (from t in _maternalcarevaluedb.Value select t).ToList();

var result = (from s in firstQuery
join k in secondQuery
on s.MotherId equals k.MotherId
where (DateTime)s.SecondVisit.Date == DateTime.Now.Date 
select s).ToList();
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: where does the exception occur and of which type are your values retrieved within the queries?

Comment: What is `s.SecondVisit.Date` and why do you have to cast it to a `DateTime`? Is it a `Nullable<DateTime>`?

Comment: Can you post where you are getting the exception along with any relevant information?

Comment: .ToList(); this conversion is causing the exception.

Comment: Please post the complete exception with stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

s is not of type DateTime, remove your cast from the query and that should fix it.

Change

```
where (DateTime)s.SecondVisit.Date == DateTime.Now.Date
```

to

```
where s.SecondVisit.Date == DateTime.Now.Date
```

Comment: If the cast fails then why should making a comparison without cast even make sense?

Comment: Because s is not of type DateTime. He is getting an invalid cast exception when trying to cast s to DateTime. I assume in the Linq query that s will be of the correct type. If that assumption does not hold up he will have to cast to the proper object. The answer my well be ((<cast to some object>)s).SecondVisit.Date but based on the code in the question I think removing the cast will solve the issue. To be honest, without more information every answer here is just a guess.

Comment: the exception is not being thrown because of the Datetime casting. It is because of toList(). function.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
var result = (from s in firstQuery
join k in secondQuery
on s.MotherId equals k.MotherId
where DateTime.Compare(s.SecondVisit.Date, DateTime.Now.Date)<=0 
select s).ToList();
```

Comment: DateTime.Compare takes 2 DateTime parameters. If the cast fails then this won't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

> the code below is throwing an "Invalid cast exception" at the first
>   line.

Looks like you have not selected the right table from your database **'_maternalvisitvaluedb'** which is giving the error.

**'_maternalvisitvaluedb.Value'** looks like a property of database and is not a table in the database. Verify if it's a table.

Comment: the error is being generated at "var firstQuery = (from s in _maternalvisitvaluedb.Value select s).ToList();".

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `Equals()` instead (which will accept nullable `DateTime` values)

```
var result = (from s in firstQuery
join k in secondQuery
on s.MotherId equals k.MotherId
where DateTime.Now.Date.Equals(s.SecondVisit.Date)
select s).ToList();
```

Also note that you're loading both tables into memory.  You *may* be able to do the query in SQL if you don't do the intermediate queries:

```
var result = (from s in _maternalvisitvaluedb.Value
              join k in _maternalcarevaluedb.Value
                  on s.MotherId equals k.MotherId
              where DateTime.Now.Date.Equals(s.SecondVisit.Date)
              select s)
              .ToList();
```

A compromise would be to do the *join* in SQL and the filter in Linq-to-objects

```
var result = (from s in _maternalvisitvaluedb.Value
              join k in _maternalcarevaluedb.Value
                  on s.MotherId equals k.MotherId
              select new {s, k})
             .Where(sk => DateTime.Now.Date.Equals(s.SecondVisit.Date)
             .Select(sk => sk.s).ToList();
```

Comment: The last sentence doesn't apply because firstQuery and secondQuery are materialized into lists.

Comment: @Dirk Thanks.  I added some suggestions to avoid loading both tables into memory.

Comment: When I try it your way , the problem is gone but it throws another different exception saying "The query contains references to items defined on a different data context." Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I didn't catch that you were using two different contexts.  In that case, my first suggestion would be appropriate, although I would strongly suggest using only one context if possible.

Comment: your first suggestion throws the invalid cast exception.

Comment: What is the type of `s.SecondVisit`?  and `s.SecondVisit.Date`?

Answer (score 0):

I know the original question has been answered, but in case anyone else bumps into this... I spent forever on this and solved it by changing

```
on (Int64)table1["myField"] equals (Int64)table2["myField"]
```

to

```
on Convert.ToInt64(table1["myField"]) equals Convert.ToInt64(table2["myField"])
```